# Choosing templating engine with extends, slots and include with parameters

Tags: handlebars.js, ejs, haml, nunjucks, templating-engine

I am building a medium size html/scss/ts website. Since it is fairly complex with a lot of repetitive elements (layouts, repetive blocks) I started researching good SSG options (ended up using 11ty) and templating engines. However, after a long search and trying multiple templating engine, I dind't found any suitable. I was looking for two points which are minimum: ability to create extend template with placeholders for content (used for layouts) and ability to include partial with parameter, and bonus - ability to provide content to partials using slot/blocks.

I tried Nunjucks, EJS, and Mustache. None of them fulfilled all criteria. Which templating engine do you use which fulfills all of the above?

Nunjucks: have extends, but you can't pass data to include (there is an option to use a macro, but doesn't look clean)
EJS: have the ability to pass data to include partial, but no option to extend

Btw, I am not interested in alternatives like Pug or Haml. Just regular HTML templating engines.

Answer (score 0):

For complex multi-page sites, I like Nunjucks the best.
Here is the [demo](https://github.com/webdiscus/demo-asia-restaurant-bundler-plugin/) multi page site using the Nunjucks template engine.

You can try the [liquidjs](https://liquidjs.com). It should fill your criteria.

This template engine support the `layout` (works like `extends`):

*layout.liquid*

```
Header
{% block %}{% endblock %}
Footer
```

*page.liquid*

```
{% layout "layout.liquid" %}
{% block %}My page content{% endblock %}
```

You can pass variables into including partials:

```
{% assign my_variable = 'apples' %}
{% include 'product', my_variable: my_variable, my_other_variable: 'oranges' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an extension for Nunjucks that adds components with slots as this was driving me nuts not having this functionality.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nunjucks-components

It allows you to use components just like Svelte or Vue etc. It works as follows.

```
<!-- component.html !-->

<div>
    <slot>This slot will be replaced with content</slot>
</div>
```

Add the component to your page.

```
<!-- template.html !-->

<h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>

<div>
    {% component "component.html" %}
        This is some text to fill the slot!
    {% componentend%}
</div>
```

I really hope someone else finds this useful.